# What is the possible use of (Monad) Option.size in scala

Tags: scala, methods, functional-programming, monads, scala-option

When we do Some(“some values”).size it returns 1. 
When we do None.size it returns 0. 
I was wondering what could be the possible use of the size method on an option.

```
val x = Some(1,2,3,4).size
println(x) // prints 1
val y = Some(List(“a”, ”b”, ”c”, ”d”))
println(y) //it also print 1
```

When we are going to have 1 for any kind of value inside Some and 0 for None. What is the use of this size method over Option.

One possible use I can think of is to know whether the option is defined in case of (Some) and size is 1 or not when None and size is 0.

But is doesn’t make sense because we already have isDefined to check that.

Comment: Wouldn't this be for consistency with the various monadic collections?

Comment: Consider `toArray` or something - it's simply useful to know the number of elements

Comment: It’s just because of consistency? I don’t think so.

Comment: @Bergi toArray.size we already have then why we should have it on option?

Comment: @RamanMishra I mean in the implementation of `toArray`, where we need to know the size of the array to allocate before filling it

Comment: Why you are talking about the toArray can you please explain it in the answer I am not getting your point. I am talking about monads which implement two methods unit and the flatMap. Monads are wrapper for the object.

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with monads. There are many monads where a `size` method wouldn't make any sense. There are also many monads for which `permutations` wouldn't make any sense. The `Option` has a `size` method because it's something like a collection with at most one element, not because it's a monad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `size` method does not have anything to do with the fact that `Option` is also a monad. The concept of a `monad` is quite general, it applies to a lot of things, and all those things will typically have many more methods that just `unit` and `flatMap`. `Option` has a `size` method because it is implicitly convertible via [`Option.option2iterable`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option$.html#option2Iterable[A](xo:Option[A]):Iterable[A]) into an `Iterable`. This makes sense, because an `Option` is a collection with at most one element.

I don't see any reason why `isDefined` should "make more sense" than `size`. None of those methods are strictly necessary. In fact, *all* methods on `Option` could be expressed in terms of `fold` only. For example, `isDefined` could be defined as

```
def isDefined = fold(false){ _ => true }
```

Likewise, `size` could also be defined through a `fold`:

```
def size = fold(0){ _ => 1 }
```

Does it now mean that we should throw away all methods except `fold`? No, not at all. "Rich interfaces" implemented as traits that provided tons of derived methods were probably the main reason why Scala's collections are so much more pleasant to use compared to, for example, Java's collections. By now, the difference has become smaller, because Java has also introduced default method implementations that do something similar, but this just shows once again that rich interfaces are inherently useful.

Answer (score 3):

The `size` method is added because `Options` are implicitly converted to an [Iterable](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/Iterable.html).  `Iterable` provides a **ton** of useful methods without having to be specifically reimplemented for `Options`.  By reusing that code, `Options` gain consistency with all other containers, and are much more reusable themselves.

In other words, it lets you pass an `Option` into a function expecting an `Iterable`, where that function only knows about methods like `size` and not `Option`-specific methods like `isDefined`.

Really, `isDefined` is the method you don't strictly need, because it only makes sense for the narrow `Option` type.  It's just there to provide a semantically nicer name than `size` or `isEmpty`.

Comment: Can you give me some link of article or something for better understanding